# Opacity of plane has no influence on points behind it

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, transparency, tikz-3dplot

I created the following figure of my data points and a regression plane:
[image]

I would like the data points above the plane to remain black but the data points below the plane to be blue. I thought this would be done automatically by the opacity of the plane but apparently this is not the case. The data file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sqfvtfd3dp3imzs/scatter3d.txt?dl=0/)

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel= stratio, ylabel=nonep,
        zlabel = testscr,
        view={115}{20},
        zmin = 510,
        zmax = 750
    ] 

    \addplot3[only marks, mark size = 0.3] file {scatter3d.txt}; 

    \addplot3[surf,domain=0:45,domain y=0:100, samples=5,
    color=blue, opacity=0.02,fill opacity=0.15,faceted color=blue]
    {686.03-1.10*x-0.65*y};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Z ordering is not done via pgfplots in such plots. So you have to cluster your points and draw them accordingly in the right order and the right layer

Comment: I think all you have to do to _see_ the points is to plot the points after the plane. But to change their Colorado you'd have to split them into two files